# Byteland Coins Array Solution

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-programming

I am finding it difficult to implement this SPOJ problem:- http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/
I found someone's code but it contains a map function which I wish to replace with an array.Here's the code:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define LL long long
map <LL,LL> ans; 

LL coins(LL n)
{
     if(n==0)
          return 0;
     else if(!ans[n])  //what does this condition check?
     {
          ans[n]= max(n,coins(n/2) + coins(n/3) + coins(n/4));
     }
     return ans[n];
}

int main() {
     LL n;
     while(scanf("%lld",&n)!=EOF)
     {
          printf("%lld\n",coins(n));
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: so, what is the problem? I can't see an actual question here... apart from that I guess that it probably won't pass all the tests if you use an array...

Comment: Please let me know if you manage to pass this problem using an array...

Comment: http://www.kodemonk.com/lastdig-the-last-digit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use array then you should better use vector.
Declare vector to hold `n` values in code above and initialize it with 0,

```
vector<LL> v(n, 0);
```

And about what condition is checked in code is nothing but whether we have found answer for `n` coins or not because by default `ans[n]` would contain 0 (but it is not good way to access nth element in a map who doesn't hold n values).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use something like (and always avoid `#define` whenever possible):

```
typedef ll_type long long;
const size_t max_size = //...
ll_type ans[max_size];
```

Comment: good luck with that: *n <= 1 000 000 000*. and besides that you probably should initialize your array, if you want to check `!ans[n]`

Comment: @dingalapadum You are correct! Hence, better we use vector and initialize it at place of declaration.

Comment: @pravar : but even if you use a vector: assuming long long is 64 bit on that machine, having a vector with 1 000 000 000 entries will use like 2GB. And most of the entries won't even be used... it simply is a bad idea to use an array for this kind of problem in the frist place... but yes, *if* you are going to use an array/vector, then initializing those 2GB is mandatory...